# Outlook Add-in to parse emails and populate Django Database

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

I'm trying to find the best way to get some sort of a button in Outlook (add-in) that will perform some functions on my django project - like parsing the email and search for a specific stirngs in it and then, populate my database.
I already achieved the population using a BaseCommand but now i want to add a button to the outlook app.
Has someone did that? is it possible?

tried https://yeoman.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Outlook add-in with a ribbon command. See [Add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) section for getting started quickly. A button control performs a single action when the user selects it. It can either execute a JavaScript function or show a task pane. The following example shows how to define two buttons. The first button runs a JavaScript function without showing a UI:

```
<!-- Define a control that calls a JavaScript function. -->
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button1Id1">
  <Label resid="residLabel" />
  <Tooltip resid="residToolTip" />
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="residLabel" />
    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_32x32" />
  </Icon>
  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>highlightSelection</FunctionName>
  </Action>
</Control>

<!-- Define a control that shows a task pane. -->
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button2Id1">
  <Label resid="residLabel2" />
  <Tooltip resid="residToolTip" />
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="residLabel" />
    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon2_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon2_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon2_32x32" />
  </Icon>
  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
  </Action>
</Control>
```

The following code shows an example function used by .

```
// Initialize the Office Add-in.
Office.onReady(() => {
  // If needed, Office.js is ready to be called
});

// The command function.
async function highlightSelection(event) {

    // Implement your custom code here. The following code is a simple Excel example.  
    try {
          // do something
      } catch (error) {
          // Note: In a production add-in, notify the user through your add-in's UI.
          console.error(error);
      }

    // Calling event.completed is required. event.completed lets the platform know that processing has completed.
    event.completed();
}

// You must register the function with the following line.
Office.actions.associate("highlightSelection", highlightSelection);
```